# will destroying a jQuery dialog remove any handlers attached to elements inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, memory-leaks, jquery-ui-dialog

I've noticed some memory leaks in an app i'm building,  after playing around with for a while FF will start to use up more and more memory (upwards to 1 000 000 k).

I've done some research and found that if i do a `$(selector).html(some stuff)`  to replace the contents of something the jQuery handlers from the elements previous content will not be removed and cause some problems, i've fixed all those.

the question i have is if i destroy a dialog with `$(mydialog).dialog('destroy');`   will the handlers that were attached to various elements that were in that dialog be removed?

Thanks!

Comment: What jQuery version? jQuery tries to clean up data on content removed from the document using `html()` (that's why it's so slow). As far as I can see, it should successfully remove event handlers; there will still be a small leak due to the id->element cache growing, but it's not that much (it was really bad in jQuery 1.3 due to a really silly behaviour causing all removed elements to receive data).

Comment: i'm using jquery 1.4.1 and jquery ui 1.8.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they will not be removed, the dialog element itself will be returned to it's previous state, the elements *inside* aren't touched.

The dialog widget itself, the buttons, title bar, close button, etc. are cleaned up, but the element you turned into a dialog is not affected and not cleaned up.  You need to either [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) or [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) the whole element for that.

Comment: ahhh, interesting. if i did a $(this).remove();   in the close callback that would take care of it yes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if destroying a dialog with the provided method removes any contained event handlers, but you can always do:

```
$(selector).empty();
```

instead of:

```
$(selector).html('blahblah'); // or .html('');
```

and that *will* get rid of any event handlers bound to any replaced elements, and thus avoid memory leaks.

Comment: yea, anywhere that i had a $(selector).html(soem stuff) i changed it to being $(selector).empty().html(some stuff)   to fix those problems.   i was more wondering what exactly destroy did.